# TCL "join" command not merging list into single string

Tags: string, join, merge, tcl

With the "join" command I've assumed tcl would merge a list of elements into a single string with delimiter.

However this is not what I see at my terminal. Also, without a delimiter it returns the same list of elements with a space in between although ideally it should merge them with no spaces

Example:

```
## Setting original string
set A [list 1 2 3]
% 1 2 3
puts [llength $A]
% 3

## Join list without delimiter
set B [join $A]
% 1 2 3
puts [llength $B]
% 3

## Join list with space delimiter (actual requirement)
set C [join $A " "]
% 1 2 3
puts [llength $C]
% 3

## Join list with comma delimiter (to also visibly check what happens to each element of list)
set D [join $A ","]
% 1, 2, 3
puts [llength $D]
% 3
foreach item $D {puts $item}
1,
2,
3
```

Not sure what is going wrong here.
I am trying to set a variable as a single string "1 2 3"

Trying to merge all elements of a list into single string.
However "join" returns the same list as initial but with delimiter added to each element of list (except last).

**EDIT:** On my new machine, the [join $A ","] is working correctly as 1,2,3 without spaces.

Comment: The **string** `"1 2 3"` equals the **list** `[list 1 2 3]`. You're using a list operation (llength) on a string that happens to be a well-formed list. This is the heritage of "everything is a string".

Comment: Is there any workaround to create a string with spaces though? I have a logical dependency on the length and I also have a need to merge the list into single string sepeerated by space. The only solution I can think of is to create 2 variables. One with string merged by space to retain string value needed for substitution later and another using a random character in join to retain length of merged string.

Comment: Also in this experiment the most weird thing I noticed is [join $A] returns "1 2 3" but [join $A ""] returns "123". As per the manual they should both work the same but not sure what is happening here.

Comment: "As per the manual they should both work the same" -- the manual states "The joinString argument defaults to a space character"; Tcl is acting as documented. To me the weirdest thing is `[join $A ","]` returning `1, 2, 3` -- where did the spaces come from?

Comment: If you have a list named A, then use list commands on it. When you need a space-separated string, `[join $A]` is the command to use. I can see the need for two variables. For example, as Donal comments below, if `set A {"first item" "second item"}` is a list of two elements. If you join that with a space separator, it becomes impossible to the split the string into the same list: which spaces are separators and which belong to list element values?

Comment: I've had to update the above query, since with a new machine [join $A ","] is working correctly as 1,2,3 without spaces. But the [join $A ""] vs [join $A] is still a mystery.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `join $A ""` and `join $A " "`?

Comment: Yes, these were all different tests to see what worked and what didn't on my machine. My understanding was that [join $A " "] would return a single string with spaces "1 2 3" and both [join $A ""] and [join $A] would return a single string without spaces "123" due to NULL delimiter. In this case however, [join $A] is rerturning "1 2 3" with spaces but explicitly specifying [join $A ""] works correctly and returns "123".

Answer (score 1):

The highly unlikely bit is this:

```
set A [list 1 2 3]
# ==> 1 2 3
set D [join $A ","]
# ==> 1, 2, 3
```

as when I put that into a fresh Tcl session I instead get a final output of `1,2,3` (and that's not behaviour anyone's planning to change). I'm guessing you have a stray space in there *or* have defined a custom version of `join`.

Comment: The weird thing is that I believe this was working when I wrote the code originally, but suddenly this bit is causing run fails in machines of other co-workers too.

Comment: I tried below on standalone tclsh with same result (with or without escaping the space using "\")
set E "";
set F "";
foreach item $A {
  append E "$item ";
  append F "$item\ ";
}

Both return as list of strings with 3 elements instead of single string.
Same issue if I create a variable as "1,2,3" and use regsub to replace "," with space.

Comment: The versions with `append` you describe will, when used with an input list of `1 2 3`, produce strings that look like lists (and that work fine as them too). If you use an input list where the *elements* contain spaces or unbalanced braces, you'll see the difference.

Comment: Thanks and yes, that is what I am running into upon inspection. What is ending up being the problem is that I was expecting [llength $A] to return 1 but its returing 3. I can still use eval to treat the values as 1 single string but my fear is that this could cause other issues in overall code.